# How to display icon inside angular material select <mat-option> and selection of the same

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to correctly display icon inside the select drop down control using material select control. After selecting mat option its selecting text of icon as well how to overcome this issue ?

```
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select formControlName="genderFormControl" placeholder="Gender">
                    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender.value">
                            <mat-icon matListIcon>pregnant_woman</mat-icon>
                            {{gender.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: did it solve the issue

Comment: No. I tried but its not displaying selected value at all.

Comment: Is there by any chance a fix for out there?
I am currently running into the exact same problem

Answer (score 8):

You can get it done  via the **`"mat-select-trigger"`** option.

```
  <mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-icon>pregnant_woman</mat-icon>&nbsp;{{gender.name}}
   </mat-select-trigger>
```

More Documentation on **[`mat-select-trigger.`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger)**

Comment: wow this is convoluted and does not even work, not answerers fault - just mat design is a hash job

Comment: not working ...

Answer (score 3):

**Complete code**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="genderFormControl" placeholder="Gender">
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender.value">
                <mat-icon matListIcon>pregnant_woman</mat-icon>
                {{gender.name}}
        </mat-option>

        <!-- MUST USE mat-select-trigger TO SHOW mat-icon -->
        <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="gender.value === 'f'">
            <mat-icon>pregnant_woman</mat-icon>&nbsp;{{gender.name}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: How are you displaying gender.name inside mat select trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Like the others said, you need to use mat-select-trigger to show set what the field looks like after you've selected an option.

This code worked in our project:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 100%">
    <mat-label>Work Ownership</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="missionForm.controls.type">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of missionTypes" [value]="type">
            <mat-icon *ngIf="type == 'individual'">person</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="type == 'group'">groups</mat-icon>
              {{ type }}
        </mat-option
            >
            <mat-select-trigger> {{ missionForm.controls.type.value }} </mat- 
            select-trigger>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```